# NodeJS SailsJS MongoDB sails-mongo module check if database connection works

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails-mongo

I am in the process of upgrading a NodeJS application using SailsJS and MongoDB.

I am using the 'sails-mongo' module to connect sails to mongodb.

I have both the application and database up and running in separate docker containers using docker-compose. Both the containers are running without any errors.

However, web application does not appear to be reading data from the database properly. In other words none of the data in the application is appearing. So I think it might be an issue with the DB connection and I want to investigate further. However, I do not have any error messages in the logs.

How can I check if the database connection is successful? Are there any log messages that I can print out to display database connection information?

Here is the datastores.js configuration:

```
module.exports.datastores = {

  someMongoDb: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    url: "mongodb://container_name_1:27017/example",
    host: 'container_name_1',
    port: 27017,
    user: '',
    password: '',
    database: 'example'
  }

};
```

UPDATE: I also attempted to connect to a cloud MongoDB and I know the url and credentials are correct. However, the same issue is happening. There are no error messages indicating a connection failure, but the previously working app is showing no data in the UI. I'm wondering if there are additional troubleshooting steps I can take to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Have you exposed port 27017 on your mongo container?

Comment: @RodrigoMata Thanks yes the port is exposed. This was all previously working until I started the process of upgrading from Node4 to Node10 and to Sails v1.0.1. I've also tested connecting to a cloud MongoDB but the same issue is happening. There are no error messages indicating a connection failure, but the previously working app is showing no data in the UI at all. Just looking for what I can do to troubleshoot.

Comment: Looking at [sails documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-datastores#?multiple-datastores), have you tried changing the options to require the adapter and join the rest of the options in the `url` parameter?